# remote ejb call trapped in the lookup in linux server 

Tags: glassfish, ejb-3.0, java-web-start

I'm using glassfish 3.1.1 with an application client container called via java web start.
My program is not working , it remain glued in the lookup() and never pass it .

```
        Context c = new InitialContext()
        geo = (GeoBeanRemote) c.lookup("java:global/server_side/server-ejb/GeoBean");
        System.out.println("end lookup");
```

I have already tested this in a windows server and it worked perfelcty but now , in the production server (ubuntu 11.04) it doesn't .
How can i fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should write your solution an an answer, and accept it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be having some routing issues. I suggest verifying your RMI port is open. The default is 3700.

Comment: it's open . I think that's the problem is caused by the /etc/hosts file .I added a new line  that contains the ip and name of the machine .Now it contains 2 lines : 127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.0.1 GlassfishServer . When i run the application it's no longer stucked in the lookup i got a NamingnotfoundException . Thanks for the help .